# Doctrine relations with multiple databases

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

The entity "Parent" stored in database database1
The entity "Child"  stored in database database2

- "Parent" is related with "Child" by attribute "childs" as
  @OneToMany(targetEntity="Child")
- "Child" is related with "Parent" by
  attribute "parent" as @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Parent")

How to get a list of Parent childs?

For example:

```
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Parent', 'database1');
$parent = $repo->find(1);
foreach ($parent.getChilds() as $child) {}
```

throws exception: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "child" does not exist

Comment: Plural of child is children FYI.

Comment: Assuming both databases are on the sane server then include the database name as part of the table name in your orm mapping.  database1.parent, database2.child.  You probably should avoid doing this but it's possible.